# hr 0x800f0203 There is no driver selected for the device information set or element

Tags: windows, com, driver, ndis

Still working on installing my LWF driver. I think I'm close but I'm running 
into this error:

"hr 0x800f0203 There is no driver selected for the device information set or 
element."

I'm verifying that I'm copying the INF and the necessary components over with 
the SetupCopyOEMInfA function. There's a lock on the device before and a release 
after that i'm omitting posting for length. The error is being thrown at the 
pncClassSetup->Install function. It's probably because I my componentId is wrong 
but I saw it was being compared to MAX_PATH in an example I found so I thought 
it was an INF file. The examples I've been working off of are:

http://www.boudrand.net/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=5
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10308583/programmatically-installing-ndis-filt
er-driver

If anyone has any insight I would greatly appreciate it!

```
hr = pnc->QueryNetCfgClass( &GUID_DEVCLASS_NETSERVICE,                     
    IID_INetCfgClassSetup,                      
    (void**)&pncClassSetup);

if (SUCCEEDED(hr))   {

    bool isCopied;
    PCSTR pathToInf =  "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\directory\\i386\\lwf.inf";
    PCSTR pathToBin =  "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\directory\\i386\\";
    PSTR DestinationInfFileName = "lwf.inf";

    isCopied = SetupCopyOEMInfA(pathToInf,                                         
     // path to inf file
        pathToBin,                                                                    
              // dir containing driver binary
        SPOST_PATH,
        0,
        NULL,
        256,
        NULL,
        NULL);

    hr = CoCreateInstance( CLSID_CNetCfg,
        NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
        IID_INetCfg,
        (void**)&pnc );

    LPCWSTR componentId;
    componentId = L"C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\directory\\i386\\lwf.inf";

    hr = pncClassSetup->Install( componentId,
        &OboToken,
        NSF_POSTSYSINSTALL,
        0,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        &pncc);


    if (S_OK == hr){        
        pncc->Release();
        pncClassSetup ->Release();

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))   
            hr = pnc->Apply();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that componentId is supposed to be the id in the INF file. In my case 
"ms_ndislwf" .

Answer (score 0):

To clarify the above reply, the first parameter to the INetCfgClassSetup::Install() method must match the hardware id indicated in the DDInstall section of the INF file. For example:

```
[Manufacturer]
"Company Name" = DDInstallSectionName, architecture

[DDInstallSectionName.architecture]
"Driver Display Name" = Name_Of_Install_Section, HardwareId
```

Filling this out with some data, we have:

```
[Manufacturer]
"Taco Distributors Inc" = TacoDriver, NTamd64

[TacoDriver.NTamd64]
"Universal Taco Driver" = Taco_Install, 123TacosADay

[Taco_Install]
AddReg...
CopyFiles...
etc...
```

In the above example, you'd need to pass "123TacosADay" to the first parameter of the InetCfgClassSetup::Install() method.